# script to load images,videos on demand in web page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Some bulletin board systems or content management systems are allowing a user to write a post with images and videos. Image and videos can be inserted with tags `img`, `embed`, etc.

What I want to do is, I want to make a reader decide to load images and videos or not. In other words, I want to put some placeholders saying *Click to load*. Images below are what I want. But it's a feature of a web browser. I want to implement it in either a server-side or a client-side.

A reason that I want this feature is, some large images, GIFs and autoplay videos are not favorable to mobile phones or to some people.

[image]
<sub>(source: [osxdaily.com](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/click-to-play-flash-example-chrome-300x251.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/click-to-play-plug-ins4.png))</sub>

A simple idea is that, examining tags `img` and `embed` with regular expression in a certain known area, e.g. `<div id="contents"></div>`. And if regular expression hits, replacing it with placeholders and a custom-made javscript or PHP function `click_to_load()`.

Before start from the scratch, I'd like to know whether there is a such library already implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do on demand loading in pure JavaScript if you want. If you want to write the function `click_to_load()` in JavaScript, all you need to do is have an image in HTML with no source, then change the source in JavaScript with the click of a button.

```
function click_to_load() {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "http://i.imgur.com/AXTI1Gr.gif";
}
```

this function changes an images source to a .gif of a cat

now just add a button with this javascript

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = click_to_load;
```

[example code that works](http://jsfiddle.net/bLsuncfd/1/)